# I am not able to fix the ReactNativeToggle Button right on the basis of backendvalue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, feathersjs

I am having a problem with a react native toggle button.
 The flow is the following :
I am expecting a value from backend either 0 or 1, on the basis of this value, my toggle turns to either true or false. 
 but the thing is I am getting a delayed response from backend where I am getting the value correct, but on view when I click on the toggle button it will go from ON>OFF>ON>OFF.

following is my code Block:-

```
  handleChange = (data) => {
    this.props.statusAvailabilityRequest(data)
  }
  render() {
    return(
     <Switch
       value = {item.status === 0 ? true : false}
       onValueChange = {() => this.handleChange({ id: item.id, status: !item.status })}
       trackColor = {{ true: '#FAC01C' }}
       thumbColor = { Platform.OS === 'android' ? '#FAC01C' : ''}
       />
    )
  }
```

Comment: Use shouldcomponentUpdate to rerender the component when you are getting the props.

Comment: At least a typo in the thumbColor = ... line - it is missing a single quote and closing curly brace in the end